# Cmake - setting visual studio intermediate dir

Tags: cmake

How do I stop CMake adding .dir to the end of of my IntermdiateDirectory?

E.g.:

```
IntermediateDirectory="libTea.dir\Debug"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no variable or property to do this.

New property VS_INTERMEDIATE_DIRECTORY_(CONFIG) can be supported by change a little code. [Here](http://fengjian.info/?p=344) is a step by step guide.

Answer (score -1):

You probably want [`RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#prop_tgt:RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY).